# Marketing Cloud - using Data Views to create a DE with all customer interactions - email and SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I'm looking to create a data extension with all email and SMS interactions for all subscribers within our SFMC account. Understand this will be a huge query and will need to be segmented in some way - like by date or job, for example. Any recommendations on this?

I'd like to include the following fields for a start - subscriber key, job id, email name, email delivered, email opened, emailed clicked, email bounced, status, date unsubscribed, date undelivered, SMS delivered, SMS opened. I'd like one record per activity ie. if a customer opened an email several times, just the first instance should be returned. And if a customer did not open an email, I'd still like an entry returned that says they were sent the email.

Many thanks for your help!
Lauren

Comment: While it can be done, I don't recommend it.  It'd be better to dump all of the data out of SFMC with tracking extracts and analyze this data in a warehouse that can handle the scale.  Broad questions like this are hard to answer on SFSE.